# get the bit stream per frame from ffmpeg record

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, h.264

Is there any way to get the bitstream per frame captured by ffmpeg. I want to capture with the raspberry pi camera in real-time and get the bitstream of the frame encoded by H.264 like I frame and P frame from the bitstream of ffmpeg. Because I want to stream frame by frame from the camera node to the server. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you planning to use a programming language, a shell script or a single FFmpeg command with arguments?

Comment: yes I would like to use python but as far as I search I only found to convert with ffmpeg. not capturing from the attached camera.

Comment: There are [examples](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam) for capturing video from camera. Why do you want to "stream frame by frame"? Why not just capturing the stream from the camera, encode it and stream it as a "sequence of bits"?

Comment: yes we want to stream frame by frame because we want to stream in real-time and also time-sensitive application. That's why. Thank you for answering question.

Comment: Are you planning to add an extra "NAL unit" between the frames (or modify the NAL units before streaming)? If you are not planning to modify the stream, there is no need to cut it into encoded frames (or cut the stream into NAL units). Simply send the stream - it doesn't affect the "real time" (doesn't affect the latency).

Comment: i'm planning to send using the message queuing like mqtt or kafka. I want to stream as one frame as one message. Therefore I would like to get the bitstream. so that i can put that bitstream as the message. Is there any way to get the bitstream of the i and p frame?

Comment: It's possible, but complicated. Take a look at my [project in GitHub](https://github.com/cohenrotem/pipe_flv2annexb).

Comment: yes I will check your project. Please allow me to ask more if I want to have questions about your project. Thanks in advance.